# how to upgrade sqlite database in user's phone

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to upgrade sqlite db by add more data to the existing db. The db is installed on user's phone. My db version is currently 1 and am trying to upgrade to 2. I didn't create onCreate method because I already have sqlite db inside assets folder which is already created by other app. I am new to sqlite. I googled this error but I don't know how to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.donghyouny.biblecard, PID: 10475
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:431)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:391)
        at com.donghyouny.biblecard.MyDatabaseHelper.insertToBible(MyDatabaseHelper.java:68)
        at com.donghyouny.biblecard.MyDatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(MyDatabaseHelper.java:62)
```

```
class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bible.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String TABLE_SAVE = "save";
    private static final String TABLE_BIBLE = "bible";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "TimeStamp";
    private static final String COLUMN_BIBLETYPE = "BibleType";
    private static final String COLUMN_VERSE = "Verse";
    private static final String COLUMN_CONTENT = "Content";
    private static final String COLUMN_NUM = "Num";
    private static final String COLUMN_CNUM = "CNum";
    private static final String COLUMN_CHECKNUM = "CheckNum";
    private static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "Image";
    private static final String COLUMN_BIBLEID = "BibleId";

    MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
       if(oldversion==1){
           insertToBible("Bible", "Psalm 1,1-2", "I am the way and truth",9, 3,  0, imageViewToByte(28));
       }
    }

    void insertToBible(String bibleType, String verse, String content, int num, int cnum, int checknum, byte[] image){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_BIBLETYPE, bibleType);
        cv.put(COLUMN_VERSE, verse);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CONTENT, content);
        cv.put(COLUMN_NUM, num);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CNUM, cnum);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CHECKNUM, checknum);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, image);
        cv.put(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_SAVE,null, cv);
        if(result == -1){

        }else {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `insertToBible()`'s signature to include, as 1st argument, an instance of `SQLiteDatabase` and remove:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

so it is like this:

```
void insertToBible(SQLiteDatabase db, String bibleType, String verse, String content, int num, int cnum, int checknum, byte[] image)
```

When you call it use `onUpgrade()`'s instance of `SQLiteDatabase`:

```
insertToBible(db, "Bible", "Psalm 1,1-2", "I am the way and truth",9, 3,  0, imageViewToByte(28));
```

Comment: I just did. Thank you again!

Comment: I have a quick question. How to find out version of my new db now? I wrote a code like this inside onCreate method but it didn't print out. Log.d("db.getVersion", String.valueOf(db.getVersion()));

Comment: onCreate() is called only if the database does not exist. Call db.getVersion() inside another method after you instantiate the db variable.